# Multiple functions for the same path in jax.ws.rs?

Tags: java, jax-rs

Lets say I wanted in implement readonly behaviour on my application (not allowing posts/puts). Could I do this by disabling these types/setting a @POST/@PUT that catches requests on any endpoint? (As opposed to putting a boolean flag on every single post/put in my application

Comment: An example in code would help us understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a filter, disallowing all the methods you don't want to support:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider 
public class AuthorizationRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private final List<String> disallowed=Arrays.asList("POST","PUT","DELETE","PATCH");

   @Override
   public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
                throws IOException {
        if (disallowed.contains(requestContext.getMethod())){
            requestContext.abortWith(Response
                    .status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN)
                    .entity("User cannot modify the resource.")
                    .build());
        }
    }
}
```